# Magento, how to get price array from grouped products?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am looking to retrieve an array with all of the final_prices for a grouped product.

The goal is to be able to use this information in product/view.phtml and display a price range that reads From: $25.00 - $899.00

I have been able to get the array somewhat working in price.phtml using:

```
$prices = array ($_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()));
print_r ($prices);
```

This will give me the array, but in the price fields of each grouped item. I need to be able to get the data and then I am thinking to use php's min & max functions to get the values with ease and display the data as shown above.

This data needs to be able to be used in the view.phtml file so this creates a bit more trouble. I have tried using price in view.phtml but it seems the function becomes quite unhappy outside of the price loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this in view.phtml file:

```
$prices = array (Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()));
print_r ($prices);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Fabrizio, this is close as it works on single products, however, the array returns no values for grouped products. Any other ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: A grouped product doesn't have a min or a max price since the quantity for the sub-items is not defined. What you could do is going through the list of grouped product items and select your min or max according to your specific logic.

Comment: Thanks, that would be doable, however, with this above code it returns the following on a grouped product: Array ( [0] => 0 ), I have been trying to adjust with out luck, this one really has me stumped. The above code works great on single priced items, but this is going to be needed for grouped products and potentially configurable products. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the timing, but you could just do the following:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($theStoreId)->load($theid)->getData('group_price');
```

When you do so, you will get the array with all the settings for the group. If you are in the customer cart phtml, is even easier:

```
$this->getProduct()->getData('group_price')
```